# Boolean field access through Lists web service

Tags: web-services, upgrade, 2003

We currently have a boolean field (yes/no) on a list that we we access through web services (getlistitems). In Sharepoint 2003 the boolean field returns as -1 and 0. While testing in 2007 for a future upgrade the same boolean field returns as 1 and 0.

Is there any documentation (or reason) for the difference in behavior? Can someone confirm that 2010 sticks with the standard 1 and 0?

Note that any comparison used on the boolean field and passed in to the service with the query parameter work just fine with 1 and 0 - it is just the return data values that have the negative.

We were hoping to not change any code during the upgrade and just point to the new server (which so far is working well) but this one field is causing a slight headache.